# NextJs Multi Zones Shared Header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have 2 apps **admin-shell** and **delivery-management** and i am using Multi Zones to handle that in NextJs.

Both these applications use a shared header with navigation links but i'm facing problem navigating from one zone to other zone.

**Admin-Shell** running on port 4201 with next.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
basePath: '/main',
rewrites: async() => {
    return [{
            source: '/delivery-management',
            destination: `http://localhost:4202/delivery-management`,
            basePath: false,
        },
        {
            source: '/delivery-management/:path*',
            destination: `http://localhost:4202/delivery-management/:path*`,
            basePath: false,
        },
    ];
},
};
```

**Delivery-Management** running on port 4202 with next.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
basePath: '/delivery-management',
rewrites: async() => {
    return [{
            source: '/main',
            destination: `http://localhost:4201/main`,
            basePath: true,
        },
        {
            source: '/main',
            destination: `http://localhost:4201/main/:path*`,
            basePath: true,
        },
    ];
},
};
```

The header is a separate shared module with navigation bar.
I'm having a problem with relative links.
Consider following links:

1- /main/main-dashboard

2- /delivery-management

When i'm in **Delivery-Management** application it appends the basePath with links like this

"/delivery-management/main/main-dashboard"
due to which the page doesnt load. It should be absolute like "/main/main-dashboard".

What could be the possible solution for this? How can i use absolute urls instead of relative urls with Next/Link.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: @vwos nah man, i shifted to Piral.io

Answer (score 0):

One of the base paths must be `/`. Considering your code, I think you should change your `/main` to just `/` and the application should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late but I came across this problem myself today and I found and **experimental** configuration features which allows for the `Link` component not adding the basePath at all so you can control from your components whether you want to include it or not in the *href*.

The property is called **manualClientBasePath** and you should add it in under the **experimental** *root property* of your *next.config.js* file.

Here is an example:

[image]