# Next.js multi zones with i18n and shared components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, internationalization, monorepo

I am using Next.js' multi zone feature with a blog and web app so I can develop and deploy both apps independently. It was easy to set up by following their [with zones example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-zones) and I have set up a blog app at port `4200` and a web app at port `3000`, which is working fine. Unfortunately I am encountering some problems that aren't described anywhere in their documentation (as far as I can tell).

First of all, I am also using their [internationalised routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing) which is working fine, however when going to my blog app it appends the locale to the end of the URL. Imagine I am on `localhost:3000/en` and navigate to the blog app, then it will show `localhost:4200/blog/en` instead of `localhost:4200/en/blog`. Is there any way around this (e.g. by using rewrites)?

Secondly, I am working in a monorepo and have shared components between both apps, such as the header and footer, which obviously includes navigation. When I am on the blog and want to navigate to e.g. the `/about` page, then it will obviously navigate to `localhost:4200/blog/about` instead of `localhost:3000/about`. One solution is to check the base path in the navigation component and then prepend `localhost:3000` to the `href` if the base path equals `blog`, but that refreshes the entire app and does not result in smooth navigation, so it's not really ideal. Is there anything else can I do about this?

Seemingly the multi zone feature is really only suitable for very small apps or I'm missing something. It seems [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65198882/nextjs-multi-zones-shared-header) also have the same problem, if I am missing something, then the documentation could definitely be at the least.

Comment: Unfortunately not @AnoopJoshiP I even [asked](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/rchvsa/vercel_acquires_turborepo_a_highperformance_build/hnuybkd/?context=3) Lee Robinson (Director of Developer Relations at Vercel) but he did not reply :(