# Difficulty routing between Next.js Multi Zones

Tags: debugging, routes, next.js, vercel

StackOverflow:
[NextJS - Issue routing between Multi Zones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73665831/nextjs-issue-routing-between-multi-zones)

There was a response on StackOverflow that covered how unfortunately you can't use next router to jump between multi zones. I want to confirm if this is still the case or improvements have been made this year.

The answer stated that "...each new multi zone is basically a new next app with its own instance of router, so for your blog app the base route would be /blog/. To jump to the other app you will have to use either an  tag with href attribute or manually change the window.location.href = .... pointing to the route you want. For example if base path is '/account' and you want to navigate to that from '/blog', you will have to do window.location.href = '/account'."

It would be really great if I could link back to the main app from a sub-app with  instead of an 'a' tag:

```
<ul>
    <li>
         <Link href="../">Home/Host App</Link>
    </li>
    <li>
        <Link href="/">Admin Home</Link>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is the tutorial that I followed:
https://www.techomoro.com/multi-zones-combine-multiple-next-js-apps/

I was expecting to be able to navigate between zones with a Link, but so far it looks like you need to use an 'a' tag.

I would really appreciate it if someone could quickly confirm if this is still the case today, or if there's a new and improved way to handle multi zone routing.

Answer (score 0):

Tested it today. It does route to secondary app with next.js Link component, but in a weird way. It takes page.js from secondary app and renders it inside layout.js of main app. A least with a dev mode. Browser's back button doesn't navigate you back to the main app, does nothing instead.